# Optional chaining property with 0 value

Tags: typescript, redux, optional-chaining

I have such code:

```
if (action?.notificationKey && state.notifications[action.notificationKey]) {
    delete state.notifications[action.notificationKey];
}
```

which does not satisfy me, because action.notificationKey can have 0 value and optional chaining condition is not fulfilled.

refactoring to:

```
    if ("notificationKey" in action && state.notifications[action.notificationKey]) {
      delete state.notifications[action.notificationKey];
    }
```

does not satisfy TS, and it underlines second condition as "TS2538: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type"

how else I can check property with possible zero value existence?

edit: modified my question as I pasted previous code version, added optional chaining as it is currently

Comment: What about `action.notificationKey !== undefined`?

Comment: you're looking for the [?? operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

Comment: Could you please modify the question as this isn't optional chaining.

Comment: @MatijaSirk yes, same result

Comment: Please provide a [mre] others can paste directly into their own IDEs to see your issue without having unrelated issues like undeclared variables.